# How to add indents on the left and right of spinners added to Custom Dialog on android?

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I've created custom dialog (from xml file), like below:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:minWidth="280dip">
   <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/subscription_quality"
    android:prompt="@string/subscription_quality_prompt">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now spinner width is equal to the width of the dialog ("`fill_parent`").
I would like to add indents on the left and right, but looks like `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found two solutions:

1. change `layout_height` to fixed value
   260dip
2. use android:`layout_marginLeft`/`Right`.